# How to inject a bean based on the property of another bean?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, strategy-pattern

I am trying to apply `Strategy` pattern (which I think I get it wrong) using Spring as following

My main class looks like

```
@Component
public class DirectoryUserImportWorkflow {
    private List<DirectoryUserDataSource> dataSources = Arrays.asList(new ActiveDirectoryDataSource(), new CsvDataSource());

    @Autowired
    private DirectoryUsersFetcher directoryUsersFetcher;

    public void run() {
        dataSources.forEach(dataSource -> directoryUsersFetcher.importUsers(dataSource));
    }
}
```

where `DirectoryUsersFetcher` is an interface as

```
public interface DirectoryUsersFetcher {
    Iterator<String> importUsers(DirectoryUserDataSource dataSource);
}
```

with 2 implementations as

```
@Component
public class ActiveDirectoryUsersFetcher implements DirectoryUsersFetcher {
    public Iterator<String> importUsers(DirectoryUserDataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("Returning data from Active Directory");
        return Arrays.asList("ActiveDirectoryUser1", "ActiveDirectoryUser2", "ActiveDirectoryUser3").iterator();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class CsvUsersFetcher implements DirectoryUsersFetcher {
    public Iterator<String> importUsers(DirectoryUserDataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("Returning data from CSV");
        return Arrays.asList("CsvUser1", "CsvUser2", "CsvUser3").iterator();
    }
}
```

I want one of them to be used at Runtime based on what the `DataSourceType` is

```
public enum DataSourceType {
    DirectoryServer,
    Csv
}
```

The `DataSource` itself is an interface which looks like

```
public interface DirectoryUserDataSource {
    DataSourceType getType();
}
```

with 2 implementations as

```
public class ActiveDirectoryDataSource implements DirectoryUserDataSource {
    public DataSourceType getType() {
        return DataSourceType.DirectoryServer;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CsvDataSource implements DirectoryUserDataSource {
    public DataSourceType getType() {
        return DataSourceType.Csv;
    }
}
```

My `test` looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DirectoryUserImportWorkflow.class, ActiveDirectoryUsersFetcher.class, CsvUsersFetcher.class})
public class DirectoryUserImportWorkflowTest {

    @Autowired
    private DirectoryUserImportWorkflow workflow;

    @Test
    public void runStrategy() throws Exception {
        workflow.run();
    }
}
```

What I see is

```
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'directoryUserImportWorkflow': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'directoryUsersFetcher': No qualifying bean of type [com.learner.datafetcher.DirectoryUsersFetcher] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: activeDirectoryUsersFetcher,csvUsersFetcher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.learner.datafetcher.DirectoryUsersFetcher] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: activeDirectoryUsersFetcher,csvUsersFetcher
```

How can I solve this problem?

**What I need?**

Based on what `DataSource` is `ActiveDirectory` or `Csv`, the specific fetcher should invoke `ActiveDirectoryUsersFetcher` or `CsvUsersFetcher`

Where am I missing the understanding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why doesn't the fetcher contain the data source in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

So, you've got two beans, with the same interface but two different names, but you know that already. Now you have multiple choices...

You could, as @crm86 suggested, simple add the `@Qualifie`r to the `@Autowired`, giving the name of the bean. This, of course, will couple your implementation tightly to the place where you use it and you will have no way to use another - except changing the code. You could also autowire not the interface but the implementing class, but of course, this is also a bad idea for the same reason - why trying to use dependency injection in the first place when then removing any choice for the container?

Another way would be to only create one instance of your `DirectoryUsersFetcher` in the first place, using a `@Configuration` and a method like...

```
@Bean
public DirectoryUsersFetcher directoryUsersFetcher () {
// decide, create, return
}
```

Of course, this will limit your application to only one fetcher per Runtime (if you don't declare them prototype - but this will require you to keep the type around somewhere, which i guess is troublesome). You would need to have the type defined somewhere anyway.

Another way would be to not create your beans directly, but use a factory pattern, for example...

```
@Component
public class DirectoryUsersFetcherFactory {

    public DirectoryUsersFetcher createDirectoryUsersFetcher (ActiveDirectoryDataSource dataSource) {
          DataSourceType type = dataSource.getType();
          if(type == DataSourceType.DirectoryServer) 
              return new ActiveDirectoryUsersFetcher ();
          if(type == DataSourceType.Csv) 
              return new CsvUsersFetcher ();
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type" + type);
    } 

}
```

This way, you could wire the factory instead of the beans directly. The factory could also cache the object, etc. Personally, i would suggest that solution.

```
@Autowired
private DirectoryUsersFetcherFactory factory;

public void run() {
    dataSources.forEach(dataSource -> directoryUsersFetcher.importUsers(factory.createDirectoryUsersFetcher(dataSource)));
}
```

Of course, your factory could also simply autowire the fetchers in the factory and return the fetchers as beans...

```
@Component
public class DirectoryUsersFetcherFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ActiveDirectoryUsersFetcher activeDirectoryUsersFetcher ;

    @Autowired
    private CsvUsersFetcher csvUsersFetcher ;

    public DirectoryUsersFetcher createDirectoryUsersFetcher (ActiveDirectoryDataSource dataSource) {
          DataSourceType type = dataSource.getType();
          if(type == DataSourceType.DirectoryServer) 
              return activeDirectoryUsersFetcher ;
          if(type == DataSourceType.Csv) 
              return csvUsersFetcher;
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type" + type);
    } 

}
```

So many choices ;-) You could even also associate the fetchers with a datasource, autowire your ApplicationContext and look through all the existing fetchers to find a suitable one, this way, your factory would not even need to know the actual implementation but could discover them at runtime... But I guess you get the basic idea...

Comment: still confused. I need to use both the beans, just need to select based on what the `DataSourceType` is

Comment: Use the factory. Wire it instead of the fetcher itself, then give the DataSourceType into the factory method and let the method create/return your apropriate fetcher.

Comment: hmm, can you direct me to an example or reference I could look up and understand?